# Atom text editor Environment variables

Tags: environment-variables, atom-editor

I did by mistake over write all my Path variables. I edited some but for Atom editor, I do not know which path should be added.

currently no package is acceable also checkForUpdate.

I have one `.atom` folder `C:\Users\UserName\.atom`  and one `atom` folder at `C:\Users\UserName\AppData\Local\atom`

I have added both paths into variables but still the same issue.

Comment: The first one is `%USERPROFILE%\.atom`. If you set the variable `%ATOM_HOME%`, it will replace `%USERPROFILE%`. The second one is `%LOCALAPPDATA%\atom`. Atom puts also some stuff (such as cache) in `%APPDATA%\atom`.

Answer (score 2):

I'd recommend downloading and (re-)installing the lastest version of Atom.

It should set the required Environment Variables automatically.